# Error main.lua:23: attempt to index upvalue 'Menu' (a boolean value)

Tags: user-interface, lua, menu, love2d

I am trying to make a main menu with lua and love2d, this is my first time doing so and sadly there are no tutorials on the matter so I took a shot at it myself. I keep runing into this error and i dont know how to fix it, Please help!

**Full error message:** *Error  main.lua:23: attempt to index upvalue 'Menu' (a boolean value)   Traceback  main.lua:23: in function 'load' [C]: in function 'xpcall' [C]: in function 'xpcall'*

Menu file

```
local Menu = {}
local game_state = 'menu'
local menus = { 'Play', 'Quit' }
local selected_menu_item = 1
local window_width
local window_height
local font_height

local Map = require("map")

-- functions
local draw_menu
local menu_keypressed
local draw_game
local game_keypressed

function Menu:load()

  -- get the width and height of the game window in order to center menu items
  self.window_width, self.window_height = love.graphics.getDimensions()

  -- use a big font for the menu
  self.font = love.graphics.newFont("assets/bit.ttf", 36)

  -- get the height of the font to help calculate vertical positions of menu items
  self.font_height = font:getHeight()

end

function Menu:update(dt)

end

function Menu:draw()
  local horizontal_center = self.window_width / 2
  local vertical_center = self.window_height / 2
  local start_y = vertical_center - (self.font_height * (#menus / 2))

  -- draw guides to help check if menu items are centered, can remove later
  -- love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.1)
  -- love.graphics.line(horizontal_center, 0, horizontal_center, window_height)
  -- love.graphics.line(0, vertical_center, window_width, vertical_center)

  -- draw game title
  love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
  love.graphics.printf("Breakout", 0, 150, window_width, 'center')

  -- draw menu items
  for i = 1, #menus do

    -- currently selected menu item is yellow
    if i == selected_menu_item then
      love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1)

    -- other menu items are white
    else
      love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
    end

    -- draw this menu item centered
    love.graphics.printf(menus[i], 0, start_y + self.font_height * (i-1), self.window_width, 'center')

  end

end

function Menu:keypressed(key)

  -- pressing Esc on the main menu quits the game
  if key == 'escape' then
    love.event.quit()

  -- pressing up selects the previous menu item, wrapping to the bottom if necessary
  elseif key == 'up' then

    selected_menu_item = selected_menu_item - 1

    if selected_menu_item < 1 then
      selected_menu_item = #menus
    end

  -- pressing down selects the next menu item, wrapping to the top if necessary
  elseif key == 'down' then

    selected_menu_item = selected_menu_item + 1

    if selected_menu_item > #menus then
      selected_menu_item = 1
    end

  -- pressing enter changes the game state (or quits the game)
  elseif key == 'return' or key == 'kpenter' then

    if menus[selected_menu_item] == 'Play' then
      Map:load()
    elseif menus[selected_menu_item] == 'Quit' then
      love.event.quit()
    end

  end

end
```

Main File

```
love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")
local Player = require("player")
local Coin = require("coin")
local GUI = require("gui")
local Spike = require("spike")
local Camera = require("camera")
local Stone = require("stone")
local Enemy = require("enemy")
local Map = require("map")
local Enemy2 = require("enemy2")
local Sound = require("sound")
local Menu = require("menu")

function love.load()
    Sound:init("music", "sfx/music.wav", "static")
    Sound:init("breeze", "sfx/breeze.mp3", "static")
    Enemy.loadAssets()
    Enemy2.loadAssets()
    Map:load()
    background = love.graphics.newImage("assets/background2.png")
    Player:load()
    GUI:load()
    Menu:load()
end

function love.update(dt)
    Sound:update()
    World:update(dt)
    Player:update(dt)
    Coin.updateAll(dt)
    Stone.updateAll(dt)
    Enemy.updateAll(dt)
    Enemy2.updateAll(dt)
    GUI:load(dt)
    Spike:updateAll(dt)
    Camera:setPosition(Player.x, 0)
    Map:update(dt)
    Menu:load()
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(background)
    Map.level:draw(-Camera.x, -Camera.y, Camera.scale, Camera.scale)

    Menu:draw()
    Camera:apply()
    Player:draw()
    Enemy.drawAll()
    Enemy2.drawAll()
    Coin.drawAll()
    Spike.drawAll()
    Stone.drawAll()
    Camera:clear()

    GUI:draw()
end

function love.playmusic()
    loopingMusic = Sound:play("music", "sfx", 0.05, 1)
    loopingMusic:setLooping(true)
end

function love.playBreeze()
    loopingBreeze = Sound:play("breeze", "sfx", 0.3, 1)
    loopingBreeze:setLooping(true)
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    Player:jump(key)
    Menu:keypressed(key)
    if key == "m" then
        Sound:stop("sfx")
    end
end

function beginContact(a, b, collision)
    if Coin.beginContact(a, b, collision) then 
        return
    end
    if Spike.beginContact(a, b, collision) then 
        return end
    Enemy.beginContact(a, b, collision)
    Enemy2.beginContact(a, b, collision)
    Player:beginContact(a, b, collision)
end

function endContact(a, b, collision)
    Player:endContact(a, b, collision)
end

function endGame()
    love.event.quit()
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your menu.lua does not return your table Menu.

So assiging `menu = require("menu")` result in `menu` referring to `Menu` but to `true`.

From the [Lua manua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-require)l:

> Once a loader is found, require calls the loader with a single
> argument, modname. If the loader returns any value, require assigns
> the returned value to package.loaded[modname]. **If the loader returns
> no value and has not assigned any value to package.loaded[modname],
> then require assigns true to this entry.** In any case, require
> returns the final value of package.loaded[modname].

So in line 23 of main.lua you're actually attempting to index true, a boolean value. `Menu:load()`

Add `return Menu` to the end of your menu.lua